# post form data to html table in DNN

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, dotnetnuke

I need your help

I have two pages in a DNN site.  1 is a form and 2 is a html table.

My question is. Is it possible to get the data from page 1 and send it to the table in page 2 in a DNN site?  If so,  do you know where I can find tutorials on how to do this?

Hope to hear from you.

Thanks!

Comment: you can write it as a simple DNN module

Answer (score 1):

If I understoud you right the answer is yes. (DNN module development is required)

```
NavigateUrl();
```

You can pass a TabID in this method to navigate to another page.

will help you reaching your goal.
you can add a string array as parameters into this method.
On page2 you can read out your parameters with the following code:

```
Page.Request[""];
```

type in the string of your named parameter.
This is a good way to transfer strings from page1 to page2.

If you want to transfer big object or something I would sugesst you that you should do it with a database or only transfering the string where you can read out your information in the DB.

The following link can help you but be carefull this is a VERY old state (about 5 years old created for DNN4 I think). Iam not sure if everything in this link is working.

[DotNetNuke 4 NavigateURL examples](http://www.adefwebserver.com/dotnetnukehelp/NavigateURL/)

hope this helps.
best regards, noone.